# Why I need to specify $switch default statement while it is optional?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to update the documents with a condition. I tried $cond, but it needs an expression for false case. And I don't want to update anything if it is false. Below is the sample of the document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc29e0d0fc2c40a9d628afe"),
    "BasicInfo" : {
        "RepNo" : "AE179",
        "CompanyName" : "First Bancshares Inc",
        "IRSNo" : "640862173",
        "CIKNo" : "0000947559",
        "Name" : "Ordinary Shares",
        "Ticker" : "FBMS",
        "CUSIP" : "318916103",
        "ISIN" : "US3189161033",
        "RIC" : "FBMS.O",
        "SEDOL" : "2184300",
        "DisplayRIC" : "FBMS.OQ",
        "InstrumentPI" : "10552665",
        "QuotePI" : "26300255",
        "Exchange" : "NASDAQ"
    },
    "Annual" : {
        "Date" : ISODate("2017-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "INC" : {
            "SIIB" : {
                "Description" : "Interest Income, Bank",
                "Value" : 66.06941
            },
            "STIE" : {
                "Description" : "Total Interest Expense",
                "Value" : 6.90925
            },
            "ENII" : {
                "Description" : "Net Interest Income",
                "Value" : 59.16016
```

Then, I tried to use $switch since the documentation said default statement is optional.

And I have written the following code:

```
db.getCollection('FinancialStatement').aggregate([
{"$unwind":"$Annual"},
{"$addFields":{"Annual.Price":
    {"$switch":{
        branches:[
        {
            case: {
                "$and":[
                {"$eq":["$_id", ObjectId("5bc29e0d0fc2c40a9d628afe")]}, 
                {"$eq":["$Annual.Date", ISODate("2017-12-31 00:00:00.000Z")]}
                ]
        },
        then: 1000}
    ],
        default: -2000
        }
        }
        }
}
]
)
```

It basically add a new field called annual.price if objectID and date requirements are met. However, if I omitt the default statement, the program returns an error saying :

```
Assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$switch could not find a matching branch for an input, and no default was specified.",
    "code" : 40066,
    "codeName" : "Location40066"
}
```

Comment: are you trying to add new field  only when condition is met ?

Comment: @Veeram Yes! Correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs on usage of `default`

> Optional. The path to take if no branch case expression evaluates to
>   true.
>
> Although optional, if default is unspecified and no branch case
>   evaluates to true, $switch returns an error.

Use `$$REMOVE` in 3.6.

Something like

Using `$cond`

```
{"$addFields":{
  "Annual.Price":{
    "$cond":[
        {
          "$and":[
            {"$eq":["$_id",ObjectId("5bc29e0d0fc2c40a9d628afe")]},
            {"$eq":["$Annual.Date",ISODate("2017-12-31 00:00:00.000Z")]}
          ]
        },
      1000,
      "$$REMOVE"
    ]
  }
}}
```

Using `$switch`

```
{"$addFields":{
  "Annual.Price":{
    "$switch":{
      "branches":[
        {
          "case":{
            "$and":[
              {"$eq":["$_id",ObjectId("5bc29e0d0fc2c40a9d628afe")]},
              {"$eq":["$Annual.Date",ISODate("2017-12-31 00:00:00.000Z")]}
            ]
          },
          "then":1000
        }
      ],
      "default":"$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: But "$$REMOVE" will remove the original data if it exists?
I only want to update the value if conditions met and leave other value unchanged.

Comment: And the conditions are actually met.Why we still need the default ?

Comment: Oh okay in that case you can use `$Annual.Price` which will keep the original value when condition is not met  instead of `$$REMOVE`. The problem arises when the condition is not met. So you have to provide both true and false path.